# Stop npm browser application from javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, process

I am running a browser application through `npm run dev` and I would like to know if there is any way to close/kill this process from the javascript script which is running.

Answer (score 0):

Call the global `process.exit(1);`

[Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html)

Comment: I cannot use `process` since it is a browser application